# BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.6 using ruby-build 20190828) Installing Ruby via rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, ruby-build

I'm trying to install `ruby 2.6.4` via `rbenv` on `macOS Mojave`

`rbenv install 2.6.4`

But every time I try it gives me:

```
ruby-build: using openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.4...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.6 using ruby-build 20190828)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/tc/ctlyg05n4czbm9wb3vvm11xr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190920102949.80278
Results logged to /var/folders/tc/ctlyg05n4czbm9wb3vvm11xr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190920102949.80278.log

Last 10 log lines:
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in '/var/folders/tc/ctlyg05n4czbm9wb3vvm11xr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190920102949.80278/ruby-2.6.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See 'config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Tried solutions so far:

1) `xcode-select --install`

2) Add missing packages in xcode
`open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

3) Reinstall `rbenv` and `ruby-build` via `homebrew` and direct

4) `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(brew --prefix readline)" rbenv install 2.6.4`

`sudo rbenv install 2.6.4` works but I want it to install without `sudo` because it leads to other complications when installing rails.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: have tried brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build then run rbenv install 2.6.3 again.

Comment: @Rakesh I have already upgraded ruby-build to `20190828`

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue about this problem. A solution from this [comment](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/798#issuecomment-395433346):

> I've resolved this issue by selecting Command Line Tools in Xcode >
>   Preferences > Locations

Did you try this way?

Comment: Yes, @demir. Still, it's not working. I even installed rvm instead rbenv, But the issue remains the same configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables